# magento2: Increase the dropdown speed of nav-menu

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, navigation, topmenu, submenu

by default nav-menu drop-down is so slow so I want the increase the drop-down time of nav-menu..

Till now I tried editing the two files but no success..
files edited: **js/navigation-menu.js**, **Magento_Theme/menu.js**

Hope some one help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your theme, make this file:

`Your/theme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/topmenu.phtml`

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php
/**
 * Top menu for store
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu
 */
?>
<?php $columnsLimit = $block->getColumnsLimit() ?: 0; ?>
<?php $_menu = $block->getHtml('level-top', 'submenu', $columnsLimit) ?>

<nav class="navigation" data-action="navigation">
    <ul data-mage-init='{"menu":{"delay":150, "responsive":true, "expanded":true, "position":{"my":"left top","at":"left bottom"}}}'>
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_menu; ?>
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getChildHtml(); ?>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The key ingredient is the `delay` option in the `menu` initialization. The default value is 300 milliseconds so here I set it to 150.

Comment: I tried changing `delay` to `150` but it seems the changes is not applied. It still loads the menu slowly. How do I verify that the delay time is actually being applied?

Answer (score 0):

Its not in your JS files, you have to check the Less files since its a CSS thing. For examples check _navigation.less on line 155 you will find

```
transition: left .3s ease-out;
```

but you can also make your own less that overwrites these values in your custom css part. Then add this and change the values in your own less files

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
    .nav-sections {
        -webkit-transition: left .3s;
        -moz-transition: left .3s;
        -ms-transition: left .3s;
        transition: left .3s;
    }   
    .nav-before-open .page-wrapper {
        -webkit-transition: left .3s;
        -moz-transition: left .3s;
        -ms-transition: left .3s;
        transition: left .3s;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer but no luck with this

Comment: Worked for me. please share your url or something so i can take a look for you\